# Edit Filter criteria in Account history?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I’m using Microsoft Dynamics 4.0. I would like to know how to add attributes to the filter option in Accounts > History. Instead of sorting by how long ago, I would like to sort by what type of task it was, Such as email, phone call, fax, service ..etc.. Is this possible? If so how would I go about implementing this change?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the Closed Activity Associated View.  It is a part of the Activity entity.  The ID should be fixed and accessible from:
From http://server:port/orgName/tools/vieweditor/viewManager.aspx?id=%7b21E2B905-6FDB-470D-8517-AD69B4C01268%7d&entityId={C821CD41-F315-43D1-8FA6-82787B6F06E7}>

Though, you'll need to publish the activity entity after making changes.  Note that this changes History for EVERY ENTITY related to activities.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Can you explain a little more?
Also when I go into the Closed Activity Associated View there are no fields to edit or anything for that matter, just a blank window you can add columns  too. Would I need to add the attributes into that column list? If so how?

Comment: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crm/thread/ba6f3f48-ca9d-4c03-9eb7-ea56eb8b975d

Here is a similar question, let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the 'Closed Activity Associated View' from the customization screen for Activity, then sort by Activity Type - also add fields, etc.